# Interrupt handler and process scheduler

Tags: linux, interrupt, scheduler

I know in Linux kernel, there is a context switching, when an hardware interrupt occurs.

I want to know one thing:

**1)**   If I am executing interrupt handler, will my process scheduler still be scheduling 
processes or it will stop scheduling until interrupt handler is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Interrupt handlers (smart ones) are split in two parts:

1. A top-half where interrupts are disabled, no scheduling. A high-priority task is then scheduled for later execution: The bottom-half.
2. A bottom-half to complete the interrupt handling.

A nice book ['Linux Device Driver: Top and Bottom Halves'](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-10-sect-4) contains more information.

Comment: thanks levif you mentioned no scheduling that means when top half is running .the scheduler is stopped until top half is completed am i correct

Comment: Correct ! interrupts are masked during top-half, so no scheduling in possible as reschedule is interrupt driven. .

Comment: Thanks levif  it was a great help from you